# Harmonic analysis needed for the Langlands program

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

I am sorry if this questions turns out to be "too broad" or "unclear", since I really know very little about the Langlands program. What I am wondering is that what kind of harmonic analysis is used in the the Langlands program.

Is it just Fourier series/transforms, or classical Fourier analysis, or abstract harmonic analysis? Or some "harmonic analysis" developed just for Langlands program theorists that are quite different from that of PDE theorists?

What are good references/online notes etc. for the harmonic analysis designated for the Langlands program?

Comment: I know you need the Fourier transform of distributions, complex analysis Dirichlet series and functional equation PNT and explicit formulas of $\zeta(s)$, algebraic number theory, class field theory, functional equation of Artin L-functions, Fourier series and integration on $\Bbb{Z_p,R/Z,A_Q}$ and criteria for  convergence, representation theory of Lie groups, decomposition of reductive groups, and of course a good experience with the classical theory of modular forms, plus the Riemann hypothesis for curves over finite fields, Galois representations, converse theorems, modularity theorem.

Comment: @reuns Thanks, do you have good references for "Fourier series and integration on "\Bbb{Z_p,R/Z,A_Q}"?